# filtrar lista de patrimônios cadastrados por sala

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou fazendo um sistema de patrimônio, onde eu posso cadastrar um patrimônio e vinculo à ele uma sala.
Neste sistema tenho uma aba de relatórios, onde tenho um campo que devo digitar o nome de uma sala e um botão para filtrar. Ao clicar no botão deveria me retornar todos os patrimônios cadastrados com aquela sala, porém ele me retorna todos os patrimônios.

Tenho a classe RelatorioController com o método buscar

```cs
public IActionResult Busca(string nome)
{
  var resultado = _relatorioService.listarPatrimonios(nome);
  return View(resultado);
}
```

E tenho a classe RelatorioService com o metodo

```cs
public List<Patrimonio> listarPatrimonios(string local)
{
  var resultado = from obj in _context.Patrimonio select obj;
  return resultado.Include(obj => obj.Local).Include(obj => obj.Equipamento).OrderBy(obj => obj.Id).ToList();
}
```

Alguém poderia me dizer onde está o erro?

model do Local

```cs
namespace CheckPatWebMVC.Models
{
  public class Local
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
  }
}
```

model do patrimônio

```cs
namespace CheckPatWebMVC.Models
{
  public class Patrimonio
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NumeroPatrimonio { get; set; }
    public string NumeroSerie { get; set; }
    public Equipamento Equipamento { get; set; }
    public int EquipamentoId { get; set; } //Garantir que o Id deverá existir
    public Local Local { get; set; }
    public int LocalId { get; set; } //Garantir que o Id deverá existir
    public string Coordenadas { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public bool Manutencao { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Poderia compartilhar os modelos das classes? Pelo que eu vi ali no teu código em nenhum momento na listarPatrimonios tu acaba filtrando pelo local. Pode utilizar um Where do LINQ para  filtrar no context de patrimônio

Comment: Obrigado pela indicação. Importa-se de apontar o que ficou diferente da resposta, para que eu possa corrigí-la? Obg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você tem uma tabela/modelo para `Local`, o ideal seria usar um combobox (ou autocomplete) para listar as opções existentes e fazer a seleção do local. Desta forma, no lugar de passar o nome, passaria o `id` do local.

Se preferir seguir como está, passando o nome do local, pode fazer algo como:

```cs
public List<Patrimonio> listarPatrimonios(string local)
{
  return _context.Patrimonio
                 .Include(obj => obj.Local) // faz join com local
                 .Include(obj => obj.Equipamento) // faz join com equipamento
                 .Where(patrimonio => patrimonio.Local.Nome == local) // filtra pelo local informado
                 .OrderBy(obj => obj.Id) // ordena pelo id do patrimonio
                 .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Continuou não dando certo, deve ser pq ele pega pelo LocalId, porem o localid so guarda o Id, vi em um curso que fazem isso para que a FK não seja nula. Pelo que andei lendo, agora eu teria que acessar pela classe PatrimonioFormViewModel que possui as propriedades public Patrimonio Patrimonio { get; set; }, public ICollection<Local> Locals { get; set; e  public ICollection<Equipamento> Equipamentos { get; set; } } mas não sei se minha lógica está correta.

Comment: @FelipeSperanza Acabei de criar um exemplo mínimo e o código acima funciona. https://github.com/tvdias/StackOverflowPT/blob/SOpt-472620/WebMvc/SampleMvc/Controllers/PatrimoniosController.cs#L24

Comment: O problema do código da pergunta é a falta do `.Where`. Quanto à FK, o entity framework cuida disso sozinho, se o seu `DbContext` não estiver com problemas.

Comment: Resolvido! obrigado a todos pela ajuda. Deu certo através do método disponibilizado no GitHub